# Создать потоковый архив

Tags: golang, потоки-данных, zip, archive

Привет всем.

Вопрос связан с разработкой backend сайта на golang. До этого я писал подобную штуку на nodejs. Для него [есть такой модуль](https://github.com/archiverjs/node-archiver), который позволяет создавать архивы. У объекта архива есть метод `pipe`,  которым можно перенаправить поток (stream) архива сразу в поток response.

Почему это хорошо? Пользователь сайта не ждёт окончания создания архива на сервере, а сразу начинает качать. Таким образом реализовано скачивание на многих сайтах.

Как можно данный функционал реализовать используя язык go? Сейчас используя `archive/zip` делаю так (следуя примеру на [сайте](https://godoc.org/archive/zip#Writer)):

```
buf := new(bytes.Buffer)
writer := zip.NewWriter(buf)
f, _ := writer.Create(name)
fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(pathToFile)
f.Write(fileBytes)
writer.Close()
http.ServeContent(writer, request, zipName, time.Now(), bytes.NewReader(buf.Bytes()))
```

*(Лишние проверки убрал намеренно чтобы не перегружать код)*

Но, естественно, сейчас пользователю сайта приходится ждать полного создания архива. Есть какой-то вариант сделать лучше?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip.NewWriter` принимает на вход `io.Writer`, которому удовлетворяет [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter). Учитывая, что файл является `io.Reader`'ом, вы можете в вашем `http.Handler`'е воспользоваться [`io.Copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Copy), чтобы не читать файл целиком.

```
zw := zip.NewWriter(w) // где w - это http.ResponseWriter
zf, err := zw.Create(name)
// проверка err
_, err = io.Copy(zf, f) // где f - это *os.File или другой io.Reader
// проверка err
err = zw.Close()
// проверка err
```

Comment: Вау, как красиво ))
Спасибо